# Rails 6 Create new record and print to printer after comfirmation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6

I have this form_with that creates a new record Post. I am trying to open the print window when the user clicks on the submit button. If rails predicts it should be something like adding onconfirm:printpage() to the Submit button but I cant seem to find how to do it.

```
= form.submit data: { disable_with: false, confirm: "Are you sure?" onconfirm: printpage() }
```

and then:

```
function printpage(){
  window.print()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do just like this:-

```
= form.submit, :class => "form_submit" ## add class to submit button

:javascript
  $(document).ready(function () { 
    $("#submit").click(function(event) {
      if( !confirm('Are you sure that you want to submit the form') ){
        event.preventDefault();
       }else{
        window.print(); 
        $('#myForm').submit(); ## your form id
       }
    });  
  });
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. window.print() goes before the submit as eventually it would not print after submitting. Please do the correction so I can accept the answer for others to use.

Comment: Is any other correction needed? if not then please accept the answer also.